# How to Store Avatar Images of Buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using Buddypress, and in that I need to to create user profile gallery for that I would be needed to store the Avatar Images, could anyone please suggest if there is any plugin or any function through which we can create some thing like this.

In short I need to create avatar galley.Is it possible..??
Please send your valuable reply or suggestion

Thanks is Advance

Answer (score 1):

it is possible, use the bp_has_members() and call the needed parameters! can be found here : 
http://codex.buddypress.org/developer-docs/custom-buddypress-loops/the-members-loop/
you can use the loop code from this page, and show only the avatar!